Laragon - I have SSL Setup but it still opens non secure site
I'm using Laragon for local dev.
I went through the Apache settings and enabled SSL, this works BUT when I use Laragon to open the site (right click > www > click site) it opens the insecure version of the site in my browser. I then have to manually change http to https to view the secure version.  This is super annoying!
Is there a way to make Laragon open the secure version by default OR auto redirect all my Laragon sites to https some other way?
Thank you!

You will find a lot of help and guidance in enhancing, configuring and customising your Laragon DevOps config. The best place to start is at the source: Laragon Discussion on GitHub.
To answer your specific question you can follow the advice of Michael Pritchard (Pen-y-Fan) as a first step: How to set up Laragon on a new Windows computer (part 4) - Enable security
Secondly, depending on your personal Local IDE setup you can try modifying the "VirtualHost.tpl" file found at "....\Laragon\usr\tpl".
The breadcrumb to the specific solution option that might work for your case is in discussion #409 by sohosynergy here in the discussion, or alternatively, another solution would be to edit your httpd.conf file e.g.:"..\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16\conf\httpd.conf" as per this part of discussion #409

If you are using Laravel
In your AppServiceProvider.php Add this code in boot() method
public function boot()
{
   URL::forceScheme('https');
}

on top use this URL facade
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

Dynamically you can use ENV variable to enable this
if (config('app.env') === 'production') {
     URL::forceScheme('https');
}

Solution 2:
Use hosts file from
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Make a https URL and point to your local IP.
